# Separating List Items Using Flexbox in a Section

Tags: flexbox

Cannot separate list items in a section.
I have spent hours changing and retrying the code. What am I not getting here?

```
<section class="award-parent">
            <div>
                <h3 class="award-title">Awwwards</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="award-right">
                <div class="award-div1">
                    <div>Site of the day</div>
                </div>
                <div class="award-div2">
                    <div>Genesis UI Kit</div>
                    <div>Application that helps to find nearest sport centres</div>
                </div>
                <div class="award-div3">
                    <div>2018</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

```
.award-parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.award-title {
    display: flex;
}
.award-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space;
}
.award-div1 {
    display: flex;
}
.award-div2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.award-div3 {
    display: flex;
}
```

[Needs to be separated like this]https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ40i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you review the foundations of flexbox layout model. Also, you might want to start with structuring your HTML markup more clearly, so that the CSS styling can be done effectively.

Below is a `flex`-based layout with modified markup.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3,
h4,
h5,
p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.award-title,
h4,
p {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}

.award-parent,
.award-item,
.award-detail {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="award-parent">
  <h3 class="award-title">Awwwards</h3>
  <div class="awards">
    <div class="award-item">
      <h4>Site of the day</h4>
      <div class="award-detail">
        <div class="notes">
          <h5>Genesis UI Kit</h5>
          <p>Application that helps to find nearest sport centres</p>
        </div>
        <time datetime="2018">2018</time>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="award-item">
      <h4>Best navigation</h4>
      <div class="award-detail">
        <div class="notes">
          <h5>Genesis Template</h5>
          <p>Application that helps to find nearest sport centres</p>
        </div>
        <time datetime="2018">2018</time>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I am studying this compared to what I had to see the differences and where I went wrong. I struggled with this for hours - even my teacher said it would be easier to do grid. I'm really impressed. Thanks for taking time to teach me.

Comment: You're welcome. It'll be worth your time to really hone your HTML skills, as it'll literally determine the whole layout structure without which you cannot really style with CSS. You could certainly use `grid` for this.